# R: Fastest way to obtain the first and last location each unique value in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector containing a list of unknown values. I would like to know the fastest way in R to obtain the first and last index of each unique values and return a n by 2 vector.

For example, the below works but I think might be too slow for large vectors.

```
library(magrittr)
vals <- sample(1:100, 1e7, replace = T)
a = t(sapply(unique(vals), function(uv) {
  w = which(uv == vals)
  c(w[1], w[length(w)])
}))
```

Rcpp solutions welcome.

Comment: I am removing the rcpp tag. SO is not a code-on-order service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And a `data.table` version could be something like

```
DT <- data.table(vals)
DT[, .(first=min(.I), last=max(.I)), by=vals]
```

Or `dplyr` which could be done with

```
tibble(vals) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
                 group_by(vals) %>% summarise(first=min(row), max=max(row))
```

The timings are quite similar to what @akrun get with the elegant base R `split` call, though, so not a lot gained there.

Comment: I suspect `DT[ , .(first = .I[1], last = .I[.N]), by = vals]` could be faster. Cheers.

Comment: @ekstroem Your solution is the fastest R only solution so far!

Answer (score 3):

The current solution can be made more efficient with `split` from `base R`

```
system.time({
 a <- t(sapply(unique(vals), function(uv) {
  w = which(uv == vals)
  c(w[1], w[length(w)])
}))

})
# user  system elapsed 
#   4.75    1.60    6.39 

system.time({
a1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(seq_along(vals), vals), 
        function(x) x[c(1, length(x))]))[as.character(unique(vals)),]
     })
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.09    0.00    0.09 


all.equal(a, a1, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or another option is `match/fmatch` which is found to be slower compared to `split`

```
library(fastmatch)
system.time({
 a2 <- cbind(fmatch(unique(vals), vals), length(vals) - fmatch(unique(vals), rev(vals)) + 1)
 })
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.45    0.25    0.70 

all.equal(a, a2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
vals <- sample(1:100, 1e7, replace = TRUE)
```